# What does $f(x)$ denote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

All

I have been reading from my textbook, and I am wondering if my textbook is just badly written since I have learned in the past that $f(x)$ means $y$ (output) and the variable $x$ is the input. However, the book is using $f(x)$ as the expression.

For example, Evaluate if $f(x) = x^3$ is odd.

Now, I place $-x$ within the parentheses and cube it. Thus, I get $-x^3$; however, I am told by the book that I can take the negative sign outside of the term $x^3$ and then it will become $-(x^3)$ and thus I can write it as $-f(x)$.

How can this be?  I thought $f(x)$ stood for the $y$ value only?

Please explain as if I am a 5 year old.

Comment: Well, if $f(x) = x^3$, then $f(-x) = -x^3 = -f(x)$ as you have described. I do not understand what exactly is your problem here.

Comment: $f(x)$ is in general an expression - in your own words, it tells you what the output should be for a given input.

Comment: Note that $(-x)^3=-(x^3)$ since $(-1)^3=-1$. Be careful placing those parentheses though, since $(-x)^2\neq -(x^2)$, for example. Your function $f$ is only odd becuase $3$ is an odd number! (Calculate $(-3)^3$ and $3^3$ and compare, then calculate $(-3)^2$ and $3^2$ and compare.)

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is just a notation for the output of a function $f$ when given a value $x$. So I take $x$ and this function $f$ gives me a number $f(x)$. That's it. So when we define $f(x)$ as $x^3$ then when we input $-x$ into $f$ we get: $f(-x)=-x^3$. But that number $x^3$ is *by definition* our function $f(x)$. So we can write $f(-x)$ as $-f(x)$.

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank You!

Comment: @Utvecklaochförenkla You're welcome. Glad it helps! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Im going to say the obvious, but here we go.
$$f(-x) = (-x)^3 = (-1\cdot x)^3 = (-1)^3\cdot x^3 = -1\cdot x^3 = -x^3$$

Therefore, $f(-x) = -x^3 = -f(x)$, this is just a property about $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a variable that denotes a function.

$f(x)$ is an expression that denotes a value: specifically, the value that is the output of $f$ when plugging in $x$ as the input.

Unfortunately, it is awkward to define a function $f$ directly. More common is to give a pointwise definition of $f$: e.g. define

$$ f(x) = x^3$$

Knowing this equation (between the variable value $f(x)$ and the variable value $x^3$) holds for all possible values of $x$ is sufficient information to uniquely identify a specific function $f$.

Unfortunately, this is still awkward for many purposes. Many people will use the expression $x^3$ when they need to denote a *function* rather than a variable quantity. This means reading mathematics can be sometimes ambiguous.

The only standard notation to allow this style while remaining unambiguous is lambda calculus: if someone writes $\lambda x.x^3$, they are referring to the function that is the same as the function $f$ defined above. Interpret this expression as saying "the function that, on input $x$, gives $x^3$". But if they merely write $x^3$ by itself, they are referring to a value and *not* a function.

Alas, this is not in general use.

Comment: Lambda calculus is of course not the only unambiguous notation for functions. The standard way is $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto x^3$. Then we have $f$ a function mapping any $x\in\mathbb R$ to it's value $f(x)=x^3\in\mathbb R$. And we could use "$x\mapsto x^3$" as a shorthand for $f$, just like "$\lambda x. x^3$".

Comment: Or you could use combinators.  Just sayin.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $$f:\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \exists f(x)|f(x)=x^3$$

is read "$f$ such that *for all/for each/for every/for any x* in  $\mathbb{R}$, *there exists* some $f(x)$ *such that* $f(x)=x^3$".

Such statements feature not only the condition ($f(x)=x^3$), but also the universal quantifier ($\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$) and an existential quantifier ($\exists f(x)$).

Unfortunately, in High School, teachers say that $f$ is the function and $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ evaluated at $x$. They then go on to say that the function is defined as $f(x)=x^3$.

Either $f(x)$ **is the function** or $f(x)$ **is the value of the function** $f$ evaluated at $x$. You can't have it both ways, Mr. Math Teacher. Stop confusing your students, and start using existential and universal quantifiers.

Don't be spooked by the symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$; they just stand for *for all* and *there exists*, respectively. And be aware that the expression

$$f:\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \exists f(x)|f(x)=x^3$$

can be rewritten in the more *englishy* form

$$f:\:for\:every\:x\in\mathbb{R}, there\:exists\:some\:number\:f(x)\:|\:f(x)=x^3$$

keeping the : and | to mean *such that*